# GCP 502 Error while while making PayPal transactions or some other place at some times

Tags: spring, paypal, google-cloud-platform

We deployed E-commerce application at GCP(google Cloud platform) which is built on hybris platform. We use payPal payment as an option that works prefectly in local developed desktop machine whereas it fails in GCP.

There are two issues with PayPal at GCP.

a) Double Call of /handleResponse( /handleResponse which get called after confirmation of PayPal payment). However, this handle response is being called two times. Some how we are able to fix this issue-(By making code change such that it handles the second call and it shows orderConfirmation page based on PayPal Session token).

b) 502 Error-- this is being thrown at some places of application at some times and after PayPal payment confirmation at GCP. After Confirmation of PayPal payment at GCP it makes three PayPal calls(each call takes around 6.87 seconds) totally it takes around 21 seconds plus one more second for the conversion of cart to order.

Totally,it would take 23 to 24 seconds for a request of PayPal payment confirmation.

Initially, our server time out has been set for 10 seconds then we increased to 30 seconds. Although, increasing time out of GCP server to 30 seconds it didn't resolve the 502 error.

Please give some suggestions to trace it down the 502 error root cause at GCP.

Cheers!!

Comment: Could you please provide more details, what GCP resource are you using (GCE, GAE, etc), also this don't seems to be related with programming so check if this don't belongs to Serverfault.

Comment: Thanks @Luke for the reply. We resolved the issue as test paypal environment takes more than 30-40 seconds to complete the process but server timeout was just 10 seconds. hence, it gives 502 error and after increasing 40 seconds its working fine.  However, at live environment paypal wouldn't take that much time to process.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main Root cause of [HTTP 502](https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939) error is caused by the longer processing time.

If a service takes more time than the configured time out, you will experience the HTTP 502 error.